# Laravel get whole database table with its associates

Tags: php, database, laravel

Is there the possibility to get whole database's table with it's associates?

My example

```php
class Gambler extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function horse()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Horse::class, 'horse_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I am fetching data of Gamblers with axios, which is being returned with this code in controller

```php
public function getGamblers () {
        echo Gambler::all();
    }
```

However I would like to get all associated Horses as well. I can get one pretty easy just like this

```php
    public function getGamblers () {
        echo Gambler::find(1)->horse;
    }
```

but maybe there is possibility to do something like this, which in my case does not work

```php
    public function getGamblers () {
        echo Gambler::all()->horse;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `return` in Controllers, not `echo`.

Because you are using `axios`, a `JsonResponse` will be more appropriate:

```
public function getGamblers () {
   return response()->json(Gambler::all(), 200);
}
```

`Gambler::all()` will return a `Collection` of `Gambler`.

On frontend, loop over the data you get from Laravel:

```
let gamblers = [];

axios.get('/your-get-gamblers-url')
  .then(function (response) {
    gamblers = response.data;
  })

gamblers.forEach(gambler => console.log(gambler))
```

If for some reson you need to do something with each Gambler in php, you can loop over the collection like this:

```
$gamblers = Gambler::all()
foreach($gamblers as $gambler) {
    //$gambler->horse
}
```